# Repurpose Content type for site pages and document library - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to repurpose the same content type for site pages and document library?  I understand the base CT for site pages is 'Site Page' vs for Doc lib it is 'Document'. Site Page is derived from Document although none of the fields (Authoring Canvas Content, Page Layout Content, Author Byline, Topic Header) in Site Page CT are currently being used specially in modern sites. So is it ok to derive a common CT from 'Document' and use it across pages and documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like site pages content types has to derive from 'Site Page' and so does the Document Content type for documents.  There is not way to have a common CT for both.